# EF core async query hangs, but sync works

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous

I have this query:

```
var groupsQuery = _context.BusinessUnitGroups
                    .Select(x => new GroupViewModel()
                    {
                        Id = x.Id,
                        Name = x.Name,
                        BuIds = x.BusinessUnits.Select(bu => bu.BusinessUnitId),
                        BuCount = x.BusinessUnits.Count(),
                        ProfileGroups =
                            new List<CpvGroupPreviewViewModel>(
                                x.BUProfileMapping.Select(a => new CpvGroupPreviewViewModel(a.ProfileGroup)))
                    }).AsNoTracking();

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dto.Name))
{
    groupsQuery = groupsQuery.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(dto.Name));
}

var result1 = await groupsQuery.Skip((1 - 1) * 10).Take(10).ToListAsync();
```

It hangs forever if I run it asynchronously, but works fine if I run it synchronously. But if I remove `ProfileGroups`, it works fine even asynchronously. This doesn't look like an `async` deadlock. I think it's because of `CpvGroupPreviewViewModel`'s constructor, but I'm not sure:

```
public CpvGroupPreviewViewModel(ProfileGroup group)
{
    Id = group.Id;
    Name = group.Name;
    ProfileCount = group.Profiles.Count;
}
```

Can someone explain why this is happening?

Comment: How do you call this function?

Comment: Where does the code execution hang? Also do you get an query translation problems in the console?

Comment: @miechooy `var paginatedGroups = await _businessUnitService.GetAllGroupsAsync(currentUid: GetUserId(Request), dto);`

Comment: I can understand EF not being able to convert constructor calls to valid sql queries, so maybe your entire db table is retrieved into memory. Assign the properties through the object initializer, without a call to your custom constructor.

Comment: @KieranDevlin `var result1 = await groupsQuery.Skip((1 - 1) * 10).Take(10).ToListAsync();` - here. No(and I don't know what is it and how should I get it).

Comment: what if you `await groupsQuery.Skip((1 - 1) * 10).Take(10).ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);`?

Comment: @Silvermind , tried it, didn't work

Comment: @zaitsman , tried it, same result

Comment: @Jamil Can you try enabling eager loading for all the used navigational properties under `BusinessUnitGroups` ? Also try commenting out the `ProfileGroup` line in the constructor of `CpvGroupPreviewViewModel` during async execution, for the time being

Comment: Are your methods in the call stack all `async`?

Comment: @phuzi, yes, all async

Comment: @bit , now that's weird. I didn't think about eager loading because this `BuIds = x.BusinessUnits.Select(bu => bu.BusinessUnitId),` worked without eager loading. But after I added all navigation properties, it worked. Why is it happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable eager loading for all the used navigational properties under `BusinessUnitGroups`. This was from personal experience although I didn't bother to dig deeper since eager loading was more efficient.

This is probably because while executing using `async`, the constructor of `CpvGroupPreviewViewModel` tries to synchronously initialize the `ProfileCount` which kind of is a deadlock.

If someone knows of a more accurate reason, please let us know.

Comment: I'll mark it as answer, but I still don't get it - same thing happens in `BuCount = x.BusinessUnits.Count(),`, and it worked this way

Comment: Agreed. Let us wait for someone with a better know-how. I have added that in the answer itself.